# Find a binomial coefficient equal to ${n\choose k} + 3 {n\choose k-1} + 3{n \choose k-2} + {n\choose k-3}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> **Exercise.** Find a binomial coefficient equal to:
>
> $${n\choose k} + 3 {n\choose k-1} + 3{n \choose k-2} + {n\choose k-3}.$$

I don't really understand what we are asked to do when we are told to find a binomial coefficient equal to the sum of some combinations, I suppose that in a combinatorial way we must show that the partition of some set S can be equal to some binomial coefficient. Can someone please give a brief explanation for the exercise?

Comment: Use $^{n}C_{r}+^{n}C_{r-1}=^{n+1}C_{r}$

Comment: Thank you @Mann but I am little confused, can you please write an answer?

Comment: The answer should be $^{n+3}C_{r}$ Try expanding the $3.Combination$ and look for pair forming the identity i stated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is $$[z^k] (1+z)^3 (1+z)^n.$$
which is $$[z^k] (1+z)^{n+3} = {n+3\choose k}.$$

Answer (score 7):

Instead of doing it algebraically, you can notice that the sum can be rewritten

$$\binom30\binom{n}k+\binom31\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom32\binom{n}{k-2}+\binom33\binom{n}{k-3}\;.\tag{1}$$

Imagine that you have $3$ red balls and $n$ blue balls. Then $\binom3i\binom{n}{k-i}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ of them so that exactly $i$ of the $k$ are red. The sum $(1)$ is therefore the number of ways to choose what from what?

Comment: Is to choose k balls from n+3 blue and red balls ?

Comment: @Admir: That’s right.

Answer (score 1):

As *Mann* already stated in his comment, the equation
$$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
holds. This is really easy to see if you are familiar with the connection between the binomial coefficients and [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Try using that and $3 \cdot x = x + x + x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\overbrace{^{n}C_{k}+^{n}C_{k-1}}+\underbrace{^{n}C_{k-1}}+\overbrace{^{n}C_{k-1}+^{n}C_{k-2}}+\underbrace{^{n}C_{k-2}}+\overbrace{^{n}C_{k-2}+^{n}C_{k-3}}$$

Applying the identity on all the pairs specified.

$$\overbrace{^{n+1}C_{k}+^{n+1}C_{k-1}}+\underbrace{^{n+1}C_{k-1}+^{n+1}C_{k-2}}$$

I am sure you can continue from here. :)